# IONIC Framework platform add IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn IONIC Framework
This is the error i get when i build on IOS. My Xcode is the latest version. I tried many method but i still get this error

> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios/3.7.0 npm http 304
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios/3.7.0 Creating ios project...
>   Unknown option: n Usage: head [-options] ...
>       -m    use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')
>       -f            make request even if head believes method is illegal
>       -b      Use the specified URL as base
>       -t   Set timeout value
>       -i      Set the If-Modified-Since header on the request
>       -c  use this content-type for POST, PUT, CHECKIN
>       -a            Use text mode for content I/O
>       -p  use this as a proxy
>       -P            don't load proxy settings from environment
>       -H    send this HTTP header (you can specify several)
>
> ```
> -u            Display method and URL before any response
> -U            Display request headers (implies -u)
> -s            Display response status code
> -S            Display response status chain
> -e            Display response headers
> -d            Do not display content
> -o <format>   Process HTML content in various ways
>
> -v            Show program version
> -h            Print this message
>
> -x            Extra debugging output Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater. Error:
> ```
>
> /Users//.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-ios/3.7.0/package/bin/create:
>   Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

Answer (score 0):

you havent mentioned the command you tried.

but here the process.

1. Install NODE.JS first
2. Install Cordova and Ionic `sudo npm install -g cordova ionic`
3. Create Ionic project `ionic start MyProject sidemenu`
4. add Platform `ionic platform add ios`